# Working with LiveData and RecycleView from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I've the below code in my `fragment`:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_settings.view.*
import java.util.ArrayList

lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
lateinit var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
lateinit var adapter: AppAdapter
val assignmentsList: ArrayList<Assignment> = ArrayList()
lateinit var appViewModel: AppViewModel

class SettingsFragment : Fragment() {
    private var listener: OnFragmentInteractionListener? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false)

        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(container!!.context) // activity as Context)
        recyclerView = layout.rvChapterList
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
        adapter = AppAdapter(container!!.context, assignmentsList)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        appViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AppViewModel::class.java)

        appViewModel.allAssgnments.observe(this, Observer { assignments ->
            // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
            assignments?.let { it ->
                println(it)
                assignmentsList.clear()
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                it?.forEach {

                    val insertIndex = assignmentsList.size
                    assignmentsList.add(insertIndex, it)
                    adapter.notifyItemInserted(insertIndex)
                }
            }
        })
        return layout
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    fun onButtonPressed(uri: Uri) {
        listener?.onFragmentInteraction(uri)
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if (context is OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            listener = context
        } else {
            throw RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener")
        }
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        listener = null
    }

    interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        fun onFragmentInteraction(uri: Uri)
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() = SettingsFragment()
    }
}
```

With the below `layout`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context=".SettingsFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvChapterList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

And the below `recycleview` layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1px">

        <LinearLayout
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <CheckBox
                    android:text="CheckBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/checkBox"/>
            <TextView
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    android:id="@+id/txtName"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:text="Occupation"
                    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvChapterName"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="26sp"
            />

        </LinearLayout>



    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Upon running it, I got below error:

```sh
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nilu.demoapplication, PID: 25646
    kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at com.oryx.geoop.SettingsFragment.onCreateView(SettingsFragment.kt:33)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2595)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:434)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2076)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1866)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1821)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1696)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:293)
        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.placeFragmentInViewHolder(FragmentStateAdapter.java:324)
        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow(FragmentStateAdapter.java:259)
        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow(FragmentStateAdapter.java:68)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchChildAttached(RecyclerView.java:7524)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView(RecyclerView.java:874)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:8569)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:8527)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:8515)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1641)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4115)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3832)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4385)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21892)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onLayout(ViewPager2.java:511)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21892)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21892)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21892)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:446)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21892)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21892)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21892)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:773)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21892)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3078)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2588)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7595)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your container is null on the first run. Use `requireContext()` instead.

```
layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
adapter = AppAdapter(requireContext(), assignmentsList)
```